# WinRT 8.1 C# - ListView performance

Tags: c#, performance, listview, memory, windows-runtime

I'm facing a trouble with my win8.1 c# app.

The problem is the performance with a ListView and thousand of items, so, I've already implemented the IncrementalUpdate, it improved the performance but it keeping worse every time the page is load. I'll describe my app scenario and any possible solution will welcome.

I have a List with about 10000 objects on the app cache (App cache it's a static class that I created to store this data and not retrieve it all the time from the database)

The listview of the page is so simple, and has a datatemplate associated with that, I'm not using DataTemplateSelector or something else.

The bind of the list is on constructor of the page, so each NavigateTo that I reference the page that will show the data will rebind the list.

I navigate to the page and back repeatedly (NavigatoTo / GoBack) and the list works fine with good performance, so, after some times doing the same thing, the performance of the list starts to decrease considerably and the itens on the list starts to getting slow to appear.

I've already tried to analyse the Memory Usage and the number of the items that is used to bind the list it's always the same, nothing increasing or decreasing because the object it's the same that it's on the memory on the App Load.

I just wanna understand a little bit more about this performance issue, because in my concept when you do a GoBack on the page, all the resources used will gone by the GC, in memory usage trace I can see the calls of the GC, but if the GC is releasing the resources, and the page it's created all the times that you use the NavigateTo, why this thing happening with my app?

This is the ListView definition:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
     x:Name="listViewProduto"
     IsSwipeEnabled="False"
     ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BlinkListViewItemStyle}"
     Tapped="ListViewProduto_Tapped" Loaded="listViewProduto_Loaded">
</ListView>
```

Here it's the bind method:

```
listViewProduto.ItemsSource = produtos;
listViewProduto.ItemTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["dataTemplateProduto"] as DataTemplate;
listViewProduto.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read this article :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780657.aspx

Is that your list has a fixed size?

Comment: Hi Philippe, thankyou for your help. I've already checked this article and it gave some lights, but I tried to implement the list virtualization changing the stackpanels to ItemsStackPanel or VitualizingStackPanel, but after change it on the data template, the app crashs and I couldn't got the error because it was out of my code.

I'll try to pay attention abou the listview size, I've already red some articles talking about this issue.

Tks

Comment: Hi Philippe, today I've been doing some changes to my code and it seens that the VirtualingStackPanel works now, the changes includes the fixed Height of the ListBox and removed grouped data to enable virtualization. It works like a charm now, thankyou very much.